# Plugin, get original function parameters in after method

Tags: magento-2.1, interceptor

When creating plugin (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) is there a way to get original parameters in after method?

I'm not sure what i can find in the first param (Interceptor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My own solution:
Use around method, and as first call the $proceed. If anyone have another solution, i would like to hear it.

```
public function aroundFooBar(InterceptorInterface $object, callable $proceed, ..args)
{
    $result = $proceed(..args)

    // after code

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2.1, the answer of @michalhosna is correct: You need to use an around plugin.

From Magento 2.2 onwards, you can access the parameters directly in an *after* plugin:

```
public function afterFooBar(InterceptorInterface $object, callable $proceed, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
{
    // after code; for example:
    $result = $arg1 . $arg2 . $arg3;

    // return the result
    return $result;
}
```

From Magento 2.2 onwards, it is recommended to use *around* plugins only if absolutely necessary, and to use *after* plugins instead if possible.
Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html